# Taylor series expansion in interval?

Tags: logarithms, taylor-expansion, interval-arithmetic

From college I remember that I can perform a [Taylor series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TaylorSeries.html) expansion for a given function *about a fixed point*.

I've found in [this site](http://www.efunda.com/math/taylor_series/logarithmic.cfm) some Taylor expansions for the $\ln(x)$ function. It shows three different forms for three different intervals:

[image]

How are these obtained?

Comment: The second and third aren't Taylor expansions. They were obtained by a nonlinear change of variable. (Applied to the seventh and first developments.)

Comment: Thanks Yves. It is still not clear to me how the first form in any case is obtained for an interval.

Comment: This is the normal behavior of an entire series, it can have a bounded radius of convergence (because the coefficients are decreasing slowly).

Comment: And now for the rest of us non-mathematicians? :)

Comment: Try evaluating for $x=3$ and you'll quickly see.

Comment: I can see it diverges. But I don't know how I'd go about obtaining that expansion for an interval.

Comment: That's sometimes what happens when you do a Taylor series expansion about a fixed point - you end up with only a finite interval where the series converges.  Are you saying you don't remember the steps needed to actually find a Taylor series expansion?

Comment: The steps are outlined [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TaylorSeries.html), I do remember that. I'm not sure how the interval appears from that.

Comment: @Gabriel: you are not constructing the series "for an interval". You construct the series about a point and it turns out that it converges only in some interval around that point.

Comment: Very well, how do I prove that? How do I prove which interval the series converges for?

Comment: Lookup "series convergence test" and in particular "ratio test".